# addEventListener callback - different options (this vs argument) - whats the difference?

Tags: javascript, callback, addeventlistener

So, basically im learning javascript... I have long since learned the basics of programming in C/C++, Java and other languages such as Matlab, and these have a defined structure of variable declaration, function declaration, etc. as well as having a defined way of doing things.

I am trying to understand the different: strengths and weaknesses of each option.

```
const pixels = document.querySelectorAll(".pixel");
pixels.forEach((pixel) =>
    pixel.addEventListener("mouseover", (e) => fillPixel(e.target))
);

function fillPixel(pixel) {
    pixel.classList.add("bg-pixel");
}
```

and this other

```
const pixels = document.querySelectorAll(".pixel");
pixels.forEach((pixel) => pixel.addEventListener("mouseover", fillPixel));

function fillPixel() {
    this.classList.add("bg-pixel");
}
```

Both do the job for me.

Just try to know the difference between two options

Comment: [`e.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) can be a descendant of `this`. Try running `document.body.addEventListener('click', e => console.log(e.target))` and click on, say, a `<table>`; you will see that `e.target` is that `<table>` element and not `<body>`.

Answer (score 0):

The value of `this` in an event handler function is equal to `event.currentTarget`, which is the element the event listener is attached to. `event.target`, on the other hand, can be a different element, such as a child element.